# Install react from bower

Tags: reactjs, npm, bower

I've got a habit to install my front end frameworks/libs via bower.
So I when I tried to install react from bower, notices that the react module is not the [official](https://github.com/reactjs/react-bower) from facebook.
Can anyone please tell me what would be the probable disadvantages of installing react from bower?

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/package-management.html#using-react-from-bower

Comment: @giorgio why down vote?

Comment: that's a habit of mine for questions which can be answered by using google or reading the documentation for specific packages for less then 1 minute

Comment: @giorgio actually googled for ``react bower module`` didn't found one. Also consider this is still a valid question in the point of SO.

Comment: Documentation is not always very clear or readable by inexperienced programmers, and as such there are tons of good reasons to ask questions which can directly be found in a documentation (eg see [this meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260743/how-to-handle-questions-that-have-answers-in-the-languages-documentation)). But in this particular case I deem the question as well as the only possible answer not helping understanding or constructive for that matter, and way too easy to be found in a documentation. If you can convince me otherwise, I will retract my down.

Comment: btw don't take the downvote personal, I don't want to encourage you to ask questions, of whatever kind. I just believe that this isn't a question that would be very helpful to others, as it doesn't add anything to to the original documentation, and as such this question/answer would be nothing more than a link to an external resource...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/package-management.html#using-react-from-bower), bower is officially supported for react. So no problems should occur.